# How to plot a bar graph with multiple columns in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have these 3 columns Sum, average, count.
And the categories `[A, B, C, D]`. Now the issue is while trying to plot the graph since the value of the sum is very large it undermines the other two plots. How can I depict this relationship appropriately?

```py
Sum_of_investments= [sum1,sum1,sum3,sum4]
avg_investments_plot=[avg1,avg2,avg3,avg4]
count_of_investments_plot = [count1,count2,count3,count4]
index = ['A', 'B', 'C','D']
plot_df = pd.DataFrame({'Sum': Sum_of_investments,'Count':count_of_investments_plot ,

'Average':avg_investments_plot}, index=index)
ax = plot_df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

I am getting this plot and clearly this isn't good enough.
To understand the scale of values here is the results

```
Avg_of_investments=957891.773, 11158747.929, 712846.782, 73318593.029
Sum_of_investments=4659879123.0 590062045968.0 16987423644.0 141927456105.0
```

If not a bar graph. What kind of graph would depict this relation in a better way?
[image: Bar Plot]

Comment: How about a log scale on the y axis?